# Leetcode 22. Generate Parentheses. Why doesn't my solution work? I'm not able to see it

Tags: python-3.x

Given n pairs of parentheses, write a function to generate all combinations of well-formed parentheses.

Example 1:

```
Input: n = 3
Output: ["((()))","(()())","(())()","()(())","()()()"]
```

Example 2:

```
Input: n = 1
Output: ["()"]
```

```
class Solution:
    def generateParenthesis(self, n: int) -> List[str]:
      openC = 0
      close = 0
      output = []
      def addC(openF, closeF, parenthesis):
        closeF += 1
        parenthesis += ')'
        if closeF == n:
          output.append(parenthesis)
          return
        
        if closeF < openF:
          addC(openF, closeF, parenthesis)
          if openF < n:
            addO(openF, closeF, parenthesis)

      def addO(openF, closeF, parenthesis):
        openF += 1
        parenthesis += '('

        if closeF < openF:
          addC(openF, closeF, parenthesis)
        
        if openF < n:
          addO(openF, closeF, parenthesis)
        else:
          return
      
      if n == 0:
        return []
      
      addO(openC, close, '')
      return output
```

I know it isn't optimized. but what's wrong with it?

Comment: Welcome to SO, indentation in python is important. I'm not sure if it was a copy and paste error, but the indentation of your code is off.

Comment: yeah i think it was a copy and paste error. but nvm, i found the solution. thank you:)